# Custom loss function problem: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I'm trying to implement a custom loss by this formula:

[image]
This is the first step to use a real custom loss function for my model. The dataset is Keras Cifar10. The implementation seems correct, But I get this error:

`OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a` tf.Tensor`as a Python`bool `is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.`

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

  #  −(log()+(1−)log(1−))

  return tf.sqrt(tf.divide(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred),2.0)),tf.cast(tf.size(y_true), tf.float32)))
```

I even have tried to cast my train_labels(which are unit8 to float32), but it wasn't helpful.
Any help would be appreciated.

My model is a simple 5-layer CNN model:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([keras.layers.Conv2D(filters= 3,kernel_size=(3,3),activation= keras.activations.relu, input_shape= (32,32,3)),
                                 keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2)),
                                 keras.layers.Conv2D(filters= 3,kernel_size=(3,3),activation= keras.activations.relu),
                                 keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size= (2,2)),
                                 keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                 keras.layers.Dense(units= 64, activation= keras.activations.relu),
                                 keras.layers.Dense(units= 10, activation= keras.activations.softmax)])

model.compile(loss= classification_loss(train_labels,model.layers[-1].output),optimizer= keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x= train_images, y= train_labels,epochs=10)
```

Comment: are u looking for the classical MSE ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Sorry for my mistake. All my problem is to implement a custom_loss even the simple predefined ones. The formula is an example of such a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the formula u used is the ROOT MSE (RMSE)

```
def RMSE(y_true, y_pred):
    
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true-y_pred)))
```

here a working example...

```
def RMSE(y_true, y_pred):
    
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true-y_pred)))

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,10))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, 1000)

inp = Input((10,))
x1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inp)
x2 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x1)
out = Dense(1)(x2)

m = Model(inp, out)
m.compile('adam', RMSE)
m.fit(X,y, epochs=5)
```